# Blender 2.8 How to scale in shape?

Tags: objects, scale

im Blender beginner and want so scale my cylinder in shape but i cant figuere out how to do it. I Tried to do it with the base cylinder and without mirror mode, in this case it work but i need to work in mirror mode.

[image]

i watch a video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lqak2bFkpA) to do this lizard but in his video it stay in shape :(
have you any hint how i can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the pivot point to 3D cursor, set the 3D cursor to he centor of the object, but lower down(i put it at the origin of the object.)  When I scaled it, it worked perfectly!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Up at the top, set the "Pivot Point" to "3D cursor" (If your in blender 2.8) If your in 2.79 or lower, it's down at the bottom, directly to the right of your viewport Shading options. (And make sure the 3D cursor is in the middle of your object)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is move it to the middle. You can move it by pressing G and then pressing either X or Y to move it in a straight line. OR You could simply turn off mirror to scale it, then turn it back on and move it towards the middle. Just make sure you have clipping on.